# XJC generated enum with Value_ with enum type

Tags: jaxb, xjc

I have an XSD with some enumerated values as below. When XJC generates the enum of the corresponding element it generates like below. Could you please let me the customization required so that it generates enum as 5("05").

```
<xsd:simpleType name="CountyCodeEnumType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>FL_CNTY_CD</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="01">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Dade</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="02">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Duval</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="03">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Hillsborough</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="04">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Pinellas</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
        </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Generated Java code

```
@XmlType(name = "CountyCodeEnumType")
@XmlEnum
public enum CountyCodeEnumType {


    /**
     * Dade
     * 
     */
    @XmlEnumValue("01")
    VALUE_1("01"),

    /**
     * Duval
     * 
     */
    @XmlEnumValue("02")
    VALUE_2("02"),

    /**
     * Hillsborough
     * 
     */
    @XmlEnumValue("03")
    VALUE_3("03"),

    /**
     * Pinellas
     * 
     */
    @XmlEnumValue("04")
    VALUE_4("04")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't name an enum value with a number. So `5("05")` is technically not possible.

You can, however customize names of enum values using `typesafeEnumMember` binding. Here's an example:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="ogc/gml/3.1.1/base/coverage.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:simpleType[@name='IncrementOrder']">
        <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="PLUS_X_PLUS_Y" value="+x+y"/>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="PLUS_X_MINUS_Y" value="+x-y"/>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="MINUS_X_PLUS_Y" value="-x+y"/>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="MINUS_X_MINUS_Y" value="-x-y"/>
        </jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

So you could do something like:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:simpleType[@name='CountyCodeEnumType']">
        <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="_1" value="01"/>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="_2" value="02"/>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="_3" value="03"/>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="_4" value="04"/>
        </jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

This would give you `_4("04")` which is quite close to what you originally wanted and does not conflict with Java syntax.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any generic solution instead of mentioning all the values one by one. I have the same problem with another enum which will have 50 values

Comment: @Debopam You could write an XJC plugin to to this on pattern basis, but, frankly, writing bindings for 50 items will be way faster.